# Core Data Relationships in pre-populated SQLite database

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

I'm new to Core Data.

Currently I have following tables on hand:

```
tbl_teahcer   tbl_student   tbl_course      tbl_student_course_map
-----------   -----------   ----------      ----------------------
teacher_id    student_id    course_id       student_id 
name          name          name            course_id   
                            teahcer_id
```

And I'm going to make the xcdatamodel as below:

```
Course                  Teacher             
------                  -------                         
name                    name                            
teacher  <<---------->  courses   
students <<---|
              |         Student
              |         -------
              |         name   
              |----->>  courses
```

My questions are as follows:

1. As I'd like to create TableView for Source Entity, is it a must to create the Inverse Relationship from Teacher to Course, and Student to Course? What is the benefit for having the Inverse Relationship?
2. I got some pre-defined data on hand, and I'd like to create a SQLite storage for pre-populated source. How can I set up the relationships (both directions) in SQLite?

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Cardinal

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inverse+relation+[core-data]

there are several discussions on inverse relationships.

1) In general: always create an inverse relation

2) write an importer using core data for your current sqlite database. Never ever read/modify the sqlite database created with core data!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Core Data with a pre-populated database.  Core Data owns the schema for it's database and should never be touched directly. So step one is to import your data into Core Data.  From there the other questions you have resolved themselves.